# JSP get the value of input tag inside dynamically generated rows of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am trying to get the value of the `input` tag which has the id `b_quantity` field but I am getting only the first row `b_quantity` value when the data is generated in the table. Every row has a different record and a button when the button has clicked the value of `b_quantity` inside this row should be targeted and not the first row the same goes for all other rows. If there is any `JQuery` or `JS` code I am willing to add it to my JSP page.

Expected Output:
When clicking the `Order` button the value of `b_quantity` in the same row should be sent to the servlet post method.

Observed Output:
When clicking the `Order` button the value of `b_quantity` in the first row is sent to the servlet post method.

```
<tbody>
    <% 

        List<Beverage> beverages = (List<Beverage>) request.getAttribute("beverageList");
        for(Beverage b: beverages) {

        %>
            <tr>
                <td  class="pt-3-half"><%= b.getName() %></td>
                <td  class="pt-3-half"><%= b.getManufacturer() %></td>
                <td  class="pt-3-half"><%= b.getQuantity() %></td>
                <td  class="pt-3-half"><%= b.getPrice() %></td>

                <% if (b.getIncentiveDTO() != null){ %>
                <td class="pt-3-half"><%= b.getIncentiveDTO().getName() %> </td>                         
                <%}else { %>
                <td></td>
                <%}%>
                <td>
                    <input id="b_quantity" type="number"  class="b_quantity" min="0" max="<%=b.getQuantity()%>" value="0">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="b_id" value="<%= b.getId() %>">
                    <!-- <input id="q_val" type="hidden" type="number" name="q_val" value="0"> -->
                    <a id="<%= b.getId() %>" href="" type="button" class="order btn btn-primary btn-lg">Order</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
    <% } %>
</tbody>
```

I am using `AJAX` to invoke the `Servlet` doPost method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".order").click(function() {
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/frontend/new?b_id=' + event.target.id ,
                type: 'Post',
                data: {
                    b_quantity: $('#b_quantity').val()
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    location.href = "/frontend/beverages";
                }
            });
        });
    });


</script>
```

Comment: id must be unique in the page.

Comment: The id is unique of the `input` tag which is `b_quantity`

Comment: Is that a typo in your example then? Certainly looks like a static string value at the moment.

Comment: What typo I have updated the question details for more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID b_quantity is not unique because you are generating rows in a table, each each row contains an input with the id b_quantity. Since the input also has the class 'b_quantity', you can use that to find the input. Try this in your click handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".order").click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var myRow = $(this).parents('tr');
        var quantity = $('.b_quantity',myRow).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/frontend/new?b_id=' + event.target.id ,
            type: 'Post',
            data: {
                b_quantity: quantity
            },
            success: function(response) {
                location.href = "/frontend/beverages";
            }
        });
    });
});


</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I am getting undefined when I click the button. I used alert quantity which returns undefined.

Comment: I made a correction: change the .parent to .parents

Comment: Yes, works it also works with  `$(this).parent('td').parent('tr');`